# old media files visble but new image files uploaded on django development admin console failing with 404 not found

Tags: python, django

I am running python 3.7/Django==2.2.6 . My issue is all old files uploaded through django admin console were accessible from media folder when i go with domain.com/media/. But when i upload a new file, it says successfully saved and i can see the file in media folder but when access it it says 404 not found. All old files in media folder still accessbile.

My settings.py

```
DEBUG = 'True'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(......), 
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you have used the ImageField ?

Comment: Here is the code ... class HomeSliderModel(models.Model):

    image = models.FileField(null=False, blank=False)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(null=False, blank=False, default=True)

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-updated']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.image.name

Comment: This issue was happening after i added sitemap.xml to the website...still i can access old image files in the media folder...but getting 404 for newly added images through admin page

Comment: Bro you haven't defined any upload_to attribute in FileField so try defining it @sam2020

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
class HomeSliderModel(models.Model): 
    image = models.FileField(null=False, blank=False, upload_to = '/user_directory_path/') 
    is_active =models.BooleanField(null=False, blank=False, default=True) 
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) 

    class Meta: 
        ordering = ['-updated'] 

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.image.name
```